# Is there a way to save all hyperlinked documents in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I know this question has been answered before, but the problem I'm facing is a bit different, and this is why I'm asking for your help :)

So, I'm working with multiple excel files that contain multiple hyperlinks that lead to documents such as Excel files, PDFs, DOCs and sometimes even images. The problem with these hyperlinks is that they are not leading to a "normal" website, but to a special internal software, that in its turn links to a local address on my computer that contatins the desired file. That means that there is no direct link that could be grabbed with a simple VBA code.

Let's have an example, assuming the internal software name is "John":
I see in the Excel documents this link:  John://3434545345/345345345
When I click on it, it opens the file, which is located, for example, in: C:/local/Cutekitten.pdf

After this long intro, my question is: Is there a way to automate the process of saving each document, instead of manually opening it and saving it? Could it be solved with a VBA code? Or does is require a different approach? I was actually thinking to bypass this problem by finding a way to open all hyperlinks at once with VBA, and then maybe find some code (not VBA?) that saves all open documents.

P.S Please keep in mind that I can't download EXE files or any other "suspicious" files due to workplace restrictions.

Any help will be much appreciated,
Thanks! :)

Comment: That `John://` looks like a custom protocol ?  What do you mean by "saving each document"?  Aren't they already saved on your computer?  I'm guessing that unless whatever executable gets run exposes the actual path you may be out of luck...

Comment: Would the filename be in the hyperlink, or will it look like the example?  You'd need to find a way of interfacing with the opening application, depending on the application determines the approach.  What would John be, an internally developed application?

Comment: If I am not completely misunderstanding the question then: (1) Use the `WorkSheets(1).Hyperlinks` collection to check all the hyperlinks 1 by 1 and then (2) use `CMD` commands to copy / save these file to the location you want them to be.

Comment: Yes, they are actually saved, but each of them is saved in a different folder, along with many other folders that I do not need. My goal is to concentrate all documents that are being linked to in the excel, to a specific folder. Is it possible?

Comment: Difficult to suggest an answer without knowing more about what your protocol handler actually does.

Comment: Hi Nathan, the filename is not indicated in link. The link consists of many number and letters. But I think it's important to say that the folders on my local PC that contain the desired files have a similar name to the "special" links in my worksheet, for example:
John://56ad4/abcd4/d5d6 (link on excel)
C:/local/0000/abcd4/1234/file.pdf

So the abcd4 is the same for both of them.

Comment: You could possibly use shell such as Dim oApp As Object oApp.Namespace(DestinationFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(nameOfFile).Items if you can figure out a way to grab the file name

Comment: You may want to use **Worksheets Hyperlinks** collection and **URLDownloadToFile function**, sample: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/67123-visual-basic-applications-save-file-website.html and from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
'''
Input: test.xlsx

name    link
1       location/file1.jpg
2       location/file2.xlsx
3       location/file3.pdf
4       location/file4.mp4
'''
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')

print wb.get_sheet_names()
# ['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2', 'Sheet 3']

ws1 = wb['Sheet 1']
## alternate -> worksheet2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')

import urllib
import os

## Result directory
directory = 'result'

if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

for row in ws1:
    if '.exe' in row[1].value:
        continue
    print row[0].value, '\t', row[1].value
    urllib.urlretrieve (row[1].value, directory+'/'+row[1].value)

'''
Output: 
Table 1     None
None    None
name    link
1   location/file1.jpg
2   location/file2.xlsx
3   location/file3.pdf
4   location/file4.mp4

'''
```

Comment: Please explain your solution by editing your answer. Especially explain why the original poster should try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PathsText()
Dim List(), Path As String
Dim i, x As Integer
Dim s As InlineShape
Dim fso As FileSystemObject, ts As TextStream

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\MyFolder\List.txt", 8, True)

With ts
.WriteLine (ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count)
End With

For Each s In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    Path = s.LinkFormat.SourcePath & "\" _
    & s.LinkFormat.SourceName
    With ts
        .WriteLine (Path)
    End With
Next s
End Sub
```

I guess the important part is if "Path = s.LinkFormat.SourcePath" works.

If so, if you have a ton of excel files to do it for, I'd put those (the ones with the links) in one folder. I'd make a new empty workbook with one button on a single sheet to call code. The button would "For Each workbook in directory, For Each sheet in workbook, For Each link on sheet" add source path to a text file.

Once you had a list of paths the next step would be obvious. I wish I had demo code, but I migrated to c# years ago. My monstrously slow cell-by-cell search, modify and graph inventions threatened to bury me.